# Android Gridview changing the selected item position

Tags: android, gridview

I have list of items in gridview. On selecting item, position of the selected item should change to 0. Every time i choose item , it should move to first position.
How can i do this?

got it

```
 temp = mFilteredBrandsList.get(position);
 mFilteredBrandsList.remove(position);
 mFilteredBrandsList.add(0, temp);
 notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: would you like to show some code so we can fix it?

Comment: Please share your adapter code.. will modify and post it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside your `onItemClickListener`.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    //assuming your grid is a list of string elements  
    String item= (String)parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    mList.remove(position);
    mList.add(0,item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Assuming mList is the main list consisting of elements inflated in grid's row.
If this isn't clear enough. SHare your code will modify the same.

Comment: got it...Thank you i did like this

Comment: Great.. just accept the answer if it worked for you. :)